# OpenMP update for Microsoft Visual C++, still stuck with version 2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang, openmp

Is it possible to substitute the OpenMP library provided by a compiler with a more recent one?

I am interested in Microsoft Visual C++ 2013, GNU GCC, Clang.

At the moment (October 2014), Visual C++ 2013 only supports OpenMP 2.0 (2001), GCC 4.9 supports version 4.0, and Clang supports version 3.1 internally, with version 4.0 coming soon.

Comment: OpenMP is not a library - it is a set of language extensions (in the form of pragmas or specially formatted comments) and a corresponding supporting run-time library. You cannot simply upgrade the support in a given compiler; you'd need a newer one that implements the new OpenMP features. With MSVC this would probably never happen as Microsoft is actively pushing its own parallel programming technologies (one could speculate that this is to make porting of such software to other platforms harder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that currently there are no plans to support a higher version of OpenMP in Visual Studio:

[take a look here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2276847-support-openmp-3-0-or-3-1)

I think, however, if you install Intel's compiler on top of Visual Studio you might be able to use a more recent version of OpenMP (as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ece116dd-0f11-4ad6-8c5a-2803068619f3/visual-studio-openmp-30-support?forum=vclanguage)). Alternatively, you can use Microsoft's PPL ([Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx)) or AMP ([Accelerated Massive Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx)).

Comment: @Pietro it seems that some of these are being ported to other platforms. For example AMP library is being actively pursued by AMD and Intel to be ported to clang/OpenCL, [e.g., here](http://www.amd.com/en-us/press-releases/Pages/developer-language-2014aug26.aspx). They are usually in beta stages, but they might be of help.

Comment: @Pietro, what's your definition of portable code in this case?

Comment: @Zboson, I mean code that can be recompiled on other operating systems and run natively.